# Achieve something like multiple inheritance in PHP

Tags: php, oop, yii

I've made an extension for Yii to wrap Amazon's SES. It works, but I don't like the structure. The source is in a [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/hanski07/yii-ses). Ideally, I want SESComponent to extend CApplicationComponent AND Mailer. You can see that I just create a property `mailer` and use that in the subsequent calls to send the mail. (maybe this is OK?...)

I really want to be able to call this using the `Yii::app()->ses` syntax, but I don't know how to properly inject the mailer dependency. I thought about trying to have Mailer implement IBehavior, and attach the behavior to SESComponent, but I don't know how to implement the methods of IBehavior.

I've looked at Yii's source code for CBehavior and there's a few classes worth of code to implement IBehavior (I think...). I'm not sure what the bare minimum code needed to implement IBehavior is. Obviously I have 4 methods to implement, but I don't know where to start, or if I'm even on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of resources to help you here. One is `behavior` the other is using [PHP Traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.phphttp://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php).

For behaviors you can follow:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/481/how-to-implement-an-event-and-attach-it-in-a-behavior/

And example extensions such as:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/remember-filters-gridview
http://www.yiiframework.com/extensions/?tag=behavior

Comment: Thanks for the sources. I should've have put the top two in my post. My concern with those is that they have a behavior class extending a CBehavior. I'd really prefer to just implement IBehavior in the Mailer class (otherwise, I'm editing the PHPMailer source by having it extend CBehavior). However, PHP Traits are looking pretty good.